# Lowest Impact OSGi container

Tags: osgi, apache-felix

I'm looking for a smallish OSGi container to install inside of what will become a network appliance type of product.  Ive been reading about the current players: Concierge, Felix, Equinox, Knoplerfish.  Concierge seems like the best contender for my purposes but it appears to have low development activity.

Is Concierge nearing end of life?

Ive run my bundles in ServiceMix so I know my stuff will work with Felix.  Should I just use that because it is more active of a project.  Is anyone out there using Concierge in a recently (2 years) delivered project and if so are you planning to stick with it?

Comment: Concierge may become an Eclipse RT project - http://www.eclipse.org/proposals/rt.concierge/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concierge is indeed tiny, however it is an OSGi Release 3 framework. For reference, Release 4 came out in 2004. As a result, few recent bundles will run on it because many rely on features that are part of the Release 4 specification.

This is perhaps not an issue if you are developing all the bundles yourself, but it will severely limit the choice of off-the-shelf bundles you can choose.

Felix would be the next up from Concierge in terms of size. It would definitely be my preferred, and is very actively developed.

Answer (score 1):

Check [mBedded Server](http://www.prosyst.com/media/prosyst_media/img_news/World%C2%B4s%20smallest%20OSGi%20solution%20-%20Technical%20Paper.pdf) - it can run on smth as small as 8 MB RAM - you can't get much lower than that :)

It is OSGi 4.2 compatible, and it is being used in many projects. There are several flavors available - for Telematics, Smart Home, Mobile...